# Notion API - Updating multiple page properties at once

Tags: notion-api, notion

Is it possible to update multiple properties with a single request? Documentation just shows a single property being changed per request

Currently trying:

```
curl https://api.notion.com/v1/pages/PageID \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer '"SHHH! Secret"'' \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Notion-Version: 2022-06-28" \
  -X PATCH \
    --data '{
  "properties": {
    "Price": {
            "number": 42
    },
    "URL to website": "https://www.google.com"
  }
}'
```

but just get the validation error as a response. But individually these properties do update

Comment: use the same schema you get in a query response, for updating and you wont face issues,

Answer (score 1):

Your solution was almost correct, you just need to fix the "URL to website" property, refer to https://developers.notion.com/reference/page-property-values for examples on all the property types

```
curl https://api.notion.com/v1/pages/PageID \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer '"SHHH! Secret"'' \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Notion-Version: 2022-06-28" \
  -X PATCH \
    --data '{
  "properties": {
    "Price": {
            "number": 42
    },
    "URL to website": {
      "url": "https://www.google.com"
    }
  }
}'
```